# for-loop in function does not append arrays while same loop outside function does append arrays

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am trying to understand the behavior of a function.

I have two arrays:

1. `a_indices`, a 5x2 array for which each row contains row and column indices of specific cells of a matrix (not relevant for this question)
2. `a_template` a 9x2 array containing values that should be subtracted from each row of 1) in order to get the indices of the neighboring cells

To subtract `a_template` from each row of `a_indices` I cooked up the following code:

```py
import numpy as np

# define arrays
a_indices = np.array([[0, 1],[1, 2],[2, 2],[0, 2],[1, 2]])
a_template = np.array([[-1,-1],[-1,0],[-1,1],[ 0,-1],[0,  0],[ 0,  1],[ 1, -1],[ 1,  0],[ 1,  1]])

# add a_template to each row of a_indices
a1 = []
for x in a_indices:
    a1.append(np.add(x,a_template))

print(a1)
```

Starting with an empty list it appends arrays with added values for each row of `a_indices`. This gives a list of 5 numpy arrays of 2x9, containing the values I need. Good!

However I will produce a lot of these `a_indices` arrays and they will likely have different numbers of rows. Therefore I wanted to wrap the above `for` loop into a function that should return my desired objects. So I tried this:

```py
def find_neighbors(idc):
    b = []
    for x in idc:
        b.append(np.add(x,a_template))
        return b

a2 = find_neighbors(a_indices)
print(a2)
```

The function just contains the `for` loop from the above example. I expected that this function returns the same object as `a1`. However it returns a list of only *one* array (the same as the first array from `a1`).

My question is why does my function not return a list for each row of `a_indices` and of course how can I fix this?

Comment: You ``return`` right after the first iteration of your loop.

Comment: Ayy, I thought it just finishes the loop and then returns the appended object. How do I fix this?

Comment: Well, it does finish your loop, and it exits your function. If you want your loop to keep running, then move the ``return`` outside of the loop. Indentation is important in Python.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I don't know if I should laugh or cry ;) It is a steep learning curve coming from R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this

```
def find_neighbors(idc):
    b = []
    for x in idc:
        b.append(np.add(x,a_template))
    return b

a2 = find_neighbors(a_indices)
print(a2)
```

your return is inside the loop. It will only give you the first array

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware that indentation played such a big role in python. I do now!